# Same origin policy and .ajax crossDomain

Tags: jquery, ajax

Same origin policy says that I can write to other origin, but I can't read from other origin. But what about jQuyery's .ajax, with crossDomain = true? I can now read other origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery, being a pure JavaScript library, is bound by the exact same limitations and security measures as JavaScript.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **crossDomain** (default: `false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests`)
>   Type: Boolean
>   If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to `true`. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.

In other words it can only force a non-cross-domain request to be considered cross-domain, but not the other way around. It has no effect when the request is actually cross-domain.